# CSS media print rules are ignored on Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, printing

The following code works well on desktop but when browsing the site on Android, it seems that the media print rules are ignored.

I copy the items I want to print to a specific DIV.
while printing, I use CSS rule to hide all other content.

On Android, it does open the print window, but with all page content. It does not hide it as asked in the print rules.

Is there a way to force android to use CSS @media print rules?

my code:

HTML \ PHP:

```
  <div id="hidden-print-div">
    <div id="hidden-print-div-header"> ...fixed logo... </div>
    <div id="hidden-print-div-content"></div>
    <div id="hidden-print-div-footer"> ...calculated date... </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
  function clickPrintCartProdList() {
    $("#my-div-to-print").children().clone().appendTo("#hidden-print-div-content"); // Copy its inner elements  
    $("body").addClass("printing");
    var originalTitle = $(document).attr('title');
    $(document).attr("title", "My Printing Title");
    window.print();
    $(document).attr("title", originalTitle);
    $("body").removeClass("printing");
    $("#hidden-print-div-content").empty();
  }
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
    body.printing #hidden-print-div { display: block; }
    body.printing #hidden-print-div #my-buttons { display: none; }

    body.printing { background-color: #ffffff; }
    
    body.printing #hidden-print-div { width: 650px; padding: 20px; }
    
    body.printing #content { display: none; }
    body.printing #footer { display: none; }    
}
```